# What is an example of an actual crystal with a primitive cell containing more than one atom?

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals, x-ray-crystallography

By definition, a primitive cell contains only one lattice point but may contain more than one atom. What is an example of a real crystal that has a primitive cell with more than one atom per cell? I looked up the INTERNET but could not find one. I am not interested in conventional/nonprimitive unit cells which contain more than one lattice points. Thanks.

Comment: Any hcp crystal has two atoms per unit cell.

Comment: Do you mean per primitive cell? HCP crystals have primitive cells with only one lattice point but two atoms?

Comment: No, the hexagonal close packed structure is a hexagonal Bravais lattice with a two atom basis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Diamond and any diamond-like materials (silicon, GaAs, etc.). The most transparent example is probably graphene (since it is two-dimensional) - its primitive cell contains two atoms (referred to as A and B sublattices), as can be seen, e.g., [in this figure](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Basis-vectors-in-the-hexagonal-lattice-of-graphene-a-and-the-corresponding-Brillouin_fig2_226894479).

Another way to wrap one's mind around this is by comparing the diamond lattice with zinc-blende structures, such as GaAs. The lattices are actually the same, but in GaAs the two atoms in the primitive cell are different, whereas in diamond they are both carbons.

Comment: Graphene example is very transparent. Thanks a lot. Do you have figures of the primitive cells of GaAs or Si?

Comment: You can google it - there are plenty of pictures, but they are all confusing, since they are in 3D.

Comment: See also the paragraph that I added to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Salt: [one sodium and one one chloride ion per unit cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_chloride#Solid_sodium_chloride).

Comment: But that is not a primitive cell. It contains more than one lattice point. I assume that you refer to the bcc conventional unit cell.

Comment: They can you edit your question to make clear what you want? -- In any case, since all primitive cells must be equal, they must contain the same type of atoms. So the primitive cell here must contain at least one Na and one Cl ion.

Comment: Actually, I did look up NaCl. But its BCC cell contains two atoms but also two lattice points. So it doesn't seem to be a primitive cell.

Comment: @mithusengupta123 The lattice of NaCl is fcc. A primitive cell must contain one lattice point. The base contains two atoms.